# Testing Spring 3.0.1 with JUnit throws Error during test

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit4

I would like to test my **Spring MVC 3.0.1** application using **junit-4.10.**jar
I am also using Hibernate(I dont know if it is relevant)

here is the test class:

```
package net.controller;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import net.service.WordService;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/spring-servlet.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class NewWordControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WordService wordService;

    @Test
    public void testController() {
        assertNotNull(wordService);
    }

}
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.testAborted(Lorg/junit/runner/Description;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
```

After quite a long googling I'm still have no idea how to solve the issue.
here is spring-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="net" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />


    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />

    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>net.model.Word</value>
                <value>net.model.Category</value>
                <value>net.model.Challenge</value>
                <value>net.model.User</value>

            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />

        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring 3.0.1 [is written against JUnit 4.7](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/inspect-pom/org/springframework/spring-parent/3.0.1.RELEASE/spring-parent-3.0.1.RELEASE.pom), so you should either update Spring to a more recent version that is compatible with JUnit 4.10 or downgrade JUnit to 4.7.

Comment: Hi, I downgraded JUnit to 4.7 but the problem still exists